# Is it bad to make a post request return a response body?

Tags: http

I'm making an api service that takes in a string, translate this string to upsidedown characters and return it.

So will the user do a POST request to me with their string, and I will give them a response body of the string turned upsidedown. Is this bad practice since it is a POST request? Or no

Comment: No, POST just moves data from the URL to the request body (and allows file uploads with multipart).    POST vs, GET has no real bearing on what an API call should return.  Many APIs use just POST for everything and ignore PATCH, UPDATE, DELETE.  Personally POST action=update seems cleaner to me than HTTP UPDATE

Comment: ... or POST /api/foo/update.php vs. create.php where the action type is a different endpoint.  RESTful purists may disagree with real-world use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what else to say, besides: This is perfectly normal for your use-case, and quite common. If you're not storing anything or create any side-effects, this *could* be a GET request with a parameters sent via the URI, but this is definitely perfectly ok.